# Update Column with Composite Referenced Value SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have an `email` column in a specific table that needs to be updated. I've know how to update `table1.email` from `table2.email`, but values do not always exist in `table2.email`.

What I'd like to do is just update `table1.email` as a composite of information from columns with values that exist in table1. The end result would be `[FirstInitial][LastName]@company.com`; `jappleseed@company.com`.

Here's what I'd like to do

```
UPDATE table1
SET   email = LEFT (table1.FirstName,1) + table1.LastName + @company.com
WHERE email IS NULL
```

I'm just not quite sure how to structure the SET.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
UPDATE table1
SET   email = LEFT (FirstName,1) + LastName + '@company.com'
WHERE email IS NULL
```

This assumes that FirstName and LastName cannot be NULL (or if either one is NULL, the email address will be NULL also), and that 'company.com' should be hard-coded and the same for everyone, rather than selected from a column in the table.

Comment: Thanks very much! The '+' were just a guess at the syntax. That's the part I really wasn't sure about.